# Why does glOrtho trigger a GL_INVALID_OPERATION?

Tags: opengl-es, sdl-2

In the following code a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is set during the call to `glOrtho()`. I cannot figure out why. Do you see what is wrong with these calls?

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  SDL_Init( 0 );
  SDL_InitSubSystem( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );

  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 1 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES );

  SDL_GL_CreateContext
    ( SDL_CreateWindow
      ( "Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1280, 768,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL ) );

  glViewport( 0, 0, 1280, 768 );
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();

  std::cout << "No error: " << glGetError() << " ?= " << GL_NO_ERROR << '\n';

  glOrtho( 0, 1280, 0, 768, -1, 0 );

  std::cout << "Invalid operation: " << glGetError() << " ?= "
            << GL_INVALID_OPERATION << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

According to [the documentation of `glOrtho`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) this error is set when the call occurs between `glBegin()` and `glEnd()`, which are not called here. In [the documentation for GLES 1.1](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glOrtho.xml) this error is even not documented.

Do you know what is happening?

Comment: Are you running on a platform that supports OpenGL ***ES*** 1.1?

Comment: `glxinfo` says `OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0`. I do not know if it means that lower versions are available or not. If OpenGL ES 1.1 is not available, why isn't there an error at initialization? Also, two weeks ago the same program worked perfectly, thus I suspect a change in the lib during a system update.